# EMI Filter - DC DC Converter No Differential Mode Filter Outlined

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emc, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

I am currently looking at installing a DC-DC Converter. https://www.xppower.com/Portals/0/pdfs/SF_QSB300.pdf

The datasheet outlines a recommended EMI filter as so:
[image]

My question is as the datasheet clearly outlines a common mode choke/filter, is it assuming I understand that the filter is not complete? I have heard to this being done in datasheets before, and also at the top of the second page in the section on notes it states (after asterisk) "Output Ripple and Noise measured with 10 µF tantalum and 1 µF ceramic capacitor across output". In which case should the final filter design look something more like this (ignore fuse and MOV as obvious)?

[image]

2nd image taken from https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/670/pybe30-din-1525731.pdf

If so why in this second image are the capacitors connected to the output lines as opposed to the chassis of the converter (CY1 and CY2)? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Different converters, different EMC specs, different EMC solutions. Output ripple and noise requires extra capacitance on output.

Comment: Indeed different converters and EMC specs, it was just an example. So the datasheet is in turn stating that it was only testing ripple for specific capacitance values as opposed to inferring the capacitors are required on output?

Comment: Some versions of that model DO require output capacitance AND to improve ripple further add the extra components you mention.

Comment: Thank you Andy aka !